# deploying bottle web applications

Tags: python, bottle

I have just finished writing a simple python web application based on the bottle microframework and I am looking for some good advice on the easiest and most efficient way to deploy the application to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

on the official website everything is explained [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#deployment) and it's pretty easy to setup

other than this, what is actually that you need to know?

Comment: got to do with hardware..what kind of hardware would be ok for this kind of application or is using heroku or amazon ec2 a better option?

Comment: i guess it's pretty much the same thing, you can run it on any dedicated linux box (for ease of configuration) aswell on heroku. i know nothing about amazon ec2, tho.

Comment: Why do you need hardware? Anyway an old HP Proliant G5 should be enough but it really depends on the load you expect to handle. If you need availability you should go with heroku, ec2 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cheap way:

- Use [Red Hat Openshift](https://openshift.redhat.com) **FREE** account with python wsgi.
- Buy a small VPS (e.g. 128-256MB ram) running Linux with nginx+uwsgi.